# shutdown or logoff script, what kind of rights does it have

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, shutdown, group-policy

In terms of a forced system reboot, from (updates, nightly patch push from HQ, etc), what type of efficacy might a shutdown or logoff script have in overcoming that?

Whether it's just running shutdown -a , or whether it's a vbs with a do loop that runs until 3=4 ... What I'm getting at is that in the past I have used shutdown scripts to do stuff prior to my PC getting automatically/forced shutdown overnight from HQ.

Since the script always worked, i"m wondering if a person could almost conclude from that, that the machine will 'ALWAYS' wait until the script is finished running?  Get my drift?

Answer (score 0):

A machine will not necessarily wait for scripts to finish execution before shutting down. A forced shutdown will always happen immediately. A properly timed `shutdown -a` should still abort it, but it's really unpredictable.

Comment: appreciate the answer; to be totally honest it seems hard to tell whether your statement comes from specific knowledge in method(s) that corporate IT uses to do this....Or are u just asserting that because it [I agree] seems to be the most likely/almost certain conclusion? Seriously not being rude - just want to know.  Because I'd like to learn an overview of the actual techniques used for this.  I'm sure there are differences..Everything from running their OWN .bat/.vbs, or them using McAfee to do something fancier...maybe they use a Win Task with trigger=event log that they generate

Comment: Just saying I was hoping to get feedback relating to actual specifics, like, "Well we did that and used this method and I know it wouldn't wait for your vbs to finish", or something.  

Cuz even your own comments say will happen immediately, then say properly timed shutdown -a should abort .. so we're not sure really ... but I do relate to what you're referring to, would be cool if I could figure out the specific method used, then I'd know if I had a chance (some shutdown methods give a window of time). All good - I'm trying several things at once, including shutdown -a - see how it goes.  :)

Comment: @Isaac I'm speaking mostly from experience. I've seen many instances when scripts were terminated abruptly by a machine shutdown. There is a such thing as a shutdown script, and the machine is designed to wait for it to complete, but even these can end abruptly depending on the source of the shutdown. I mention that a forced shutdown `shutdown -f` can still be aborted, and that is a true statement. However, the window for passing the `shutdown -a` command is very small and the explorer.exe process and those attached are the first to go making it that much smaller.